# How to remove an array element from a Sub-Subdocument

Tags: mongoose

I have a document with the following layout:

```
{
    "A1" : {
        "B1" : {
            "C1" : [ 
                ObjectId("123"),
                ObjectId("456")
            ],
            "C2" : [ 
                ObjectId("789"),
                ObjectId("abc")
            ]
        },
        "B2" : {
            "C1" : [ 
                ObjectId("def"),
                ObjectId("hij")
            ],
            "C2" : [ 
                ObjectId("klm"),
                ObjectId("nop")
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to delete one of the array elements from `A1.B1.C1` using their ID.

I'm using the following update code:

```
{
    "A1" : {
        "B1" : {
            "$pull" : {
                "C1" : "123"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that results in the following:

```
{
    "A1" : {
        "B1" : {}
    }
}
```

I've tried different variations of the update code, for example:

```
{
    "A1" : {
        "B1" : {
            "C1" : {
                "$pull" : "123"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that results in the following error:

```
Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[{"$pull":"123"}]"
```

Could someone provide some guidance as on how to remove a specific array element from a sub-sub-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
"$pull" : {
   "A1.B1.C1" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("123")
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks! You're now my most favourite person!